# Get exit code from powershell command in a script and passing it to Jenkins

Tags: powershell, batch-file, jenkins

I'm reading around about how to get the error from a powershell script and passing it around to the batch file calling it. The bacth file is just a Jenkins build step (Execute Win batch) and it's as simple as that:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\Users\hicciuser\invoke.ps1
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
exit %ERRORLEVEL%
```

The powershell script is remarkably simple:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://random.url" -TimeoutSec 2
Exit $LASTEXITCODE
```

Turns out that, if the web request fails (times out in this case), then the `%ERRORLEVEL%` still seems to be 0.

If, in the script, I do `Exit 1` then the `%ERRORLEVEL%` is set up correctly, so it seems that the `Invoke-WebRequest` command is not setting the right exit code on failure. Is there a simpler way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: Is your batch file code snippet part of a code block enclosed in `()`?

Comment: Nope, it's just those three lines, entered in the textbox provided by Jenkins for the Exec Windows Batch build step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I went for this solution, but I would really like to know how to get a proper error code return from `Invoke-WebRequest` (or any other CmdLet):

```
$failing = 0
$Error.Clear()
try { 
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url 
}
catch { 
    Write-Host $Error
    $failing = 1 
}
Exit $failing
```

At least I can get an exit code that's not zero and Jenkins will be happy and fail the build.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exit with the response status code you could do something like:

```
try { 
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url 
    Exit 0
}
catch { 
    Exit $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.Value__
}
```

Comment: Interesting but a Timeout error does not have a status code, so it will keep Exiting 0...